# IPython: turn off %timeit message about "This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached"

Tags: ipython

Since upgrading to IPython version 3 (I have 3.1.0), every time I use the `%timeit` command, it prints "The slowest run took [number] times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached" before printing the timing results.  This happens even for very simple operations.  For example:

```
In [4]: x = 5

In [5]: %timeit x
The slowest run took 53.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000000 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ns per loop
```

and:

```
In [17]: %timeit 22 + 1
The slowest run took 106.15 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ns per loop
```

There are only a few cases where I can get it to not happen, like:

```
In [15]: %timeit 5
100000000 loops, best of 3: 8.37 ns per loop
```

I understand that there's probably some caching going on at some level (for example as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759883/what-does-an-intermediate-result-is-being-cached-mean)), but the message is distracting and not really useful.  Is there any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%timeit -q` will be silent, and the `-o` option will return the result. This is slightly different, but should do the trick.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't even know the magic functions could take flags or return results.  I'll try to see if there's a way to give it default flags without typing them every time, but this solution is definitely better than nothing.