# How to set matrix columns iteratively and fast?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have the following Python code:

```
H = np.zeros(shape=(N-q+1,q),dtype=complex)
for i in range(0,N-q+1):
    H[i,:] = u[i:q+i]
```

where *N* and *q* are constants and *u* is a vector long enough so no out of bounds error would occur when *u[i:q+i]*.

I have tried to optimize the code by using list comprehension,

```
H = np.asarray([u[i:q+i] for i in range(0,N-q+1)])
```

but *np.asarray()* makes it slower than previous code.

Any idea in order to optimize the assignation of column values?

Comment: I remember there being an existing routine that does this or something very closely related, but I can't remember what it was. The simplicity of the sequence of `i` values means you could do this with explicit stride manipulation, if there isn't an existing routine.

Comment: Wait, no, I was thinking of something else.

Comment: Can you add an example that actually runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`stride.as_strided`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html):

```
import numpy.lib.stride_tricks as stride

s = u.strides[0]
H2 = stride.as_strided(u, shape=(N-q+1,q), strides=(s, s)).astype(complex)
```

Using `strides=(s, s)` is the key -- in particular, making the first stride `s` means that each row of `H2` advances the index into `u` by the number of bytes needed to advance one item. Hence the rows repeat, albeit shifted by one.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.stride_tricks as stride

N, q = 10**2, 6
u = np.arange((N-q+1)*(N))

def using_loop(u):
    H = np.zeros(shape=(N-q+1,q),dtype=complex)
    for i in range(0,N-q+1):
        H[i,:] = u[i:q+i]
    return H

def using_stride(u):
    s = u.strides[0]
    H2 = stride.as_strided(u, shape=(N-q+1,q), strides=(s, s)).astype(complex)
    return H2

H = using_loop(u)
H2 = using_stride(u)
assert np.allclose(H, H2)
```

---

Since `stride.as_strided` avoids the Python `for-loop`, `using_stride` is faster than `using_loop`. The advantage grows as `N-q` (the number of iterations) increases.

With N = 10**2 `using_stride` is 5x faster:

```
In [119]: %timeit using_loop(u)
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.6 µs per loop

In [120]: %timeit using_stride(u)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.9 µs per loop
```

With N = 10**3 `using_stride` is 28x faster:

```
In [122]: %timeit using_loop(u)
1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop

In [123]: %timeit using_stride(u)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: How is the performance of this?

Comment: Pretty cool. Do you see any more room for improvement?

Comment: My python says about your stride example: The slowest run took 6.84 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.66 µs per loop. This makes the result suspicious

Comment: I mean that there is a large spread in the samples that come out of the stride routine. I do reproduce the huge performance increase, so your method is great.

Comment: @Chiel: The warning may be due to the array(s) being in the CPU cache. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29759883/190597. Since I get the same warning for `using_loop` and `using_stride`, and they use the same arrays, I think the comparison is fair.

Comment: Using `u.itemsize` for the strides has the issue of assuming the input is contiguous. It's more robust to take the stride from `u.strides`.

Comment: @user2357112: Good point. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks! Huge improvement.